# Passing variables from one JS file into another JS file

Tags: javascript

my use case is that I am trying to pass my ecommerce data into a html page.

Currently in my first js file (main.js)  I am doing this:

```
  $('.order-checkout').click(function() {
    console.log("checkout")
    window.localStorage.removeItem('data');
    data = JSON.stringify(shoppingCart.listCart())
    console.log(data)
    localStorage.setItem("object_name",data);

  });
```

This is some sample data which i am  trying  to pass over:

```
[{"name":"Marvel_Black_T-shirt","price":20,"count":1,"total":"20.00"},{"name":"DC_Black_T-shirt","price":35,"count":1,"total":"35.00"}]
```

I have a second js file (checkout.js) where I am doing this below. For this JS file is being used by my checkout.html page

```
var data;
var total_amount;

var data = localStorage.getItem("object_name");
console.log(data)
console.log ("debug")
results = JSON.parse(data)

console.log(results)
localStorage.clear();
document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
const orderTotal = document.getElementById('order-total');
orderTotal.querySelector('[data-total]').innerText = results[0].total
```

I  notice that sometimes my console.log is inconsistent...it may not print the debug message and my `orderTotal.querySelector('[data-total]').innerText = results[0].total`is not being set.

Is this the best way to use local storage?  Any other suggestions on how I go about this?